# Scratch lottery function

Tags: python

I am working on a scratch lottery command on my python game.

My Scratch lottery function is below.

```
def lottery(player_money):
    print('scratch lottery :')
    print('price: 500')
    print('wins :')
    print('    all 6 same : $100000')
    print('    all 5 same : $50000')
    print('    all 4 same : $10000')
    print('    all 3 same : $1000')
    print('    all 2 same : $300')
    print('do you want to buy it?? yes/no')
    buy = input('>  ')
    if buy == 'no':
        print('please come back later!!')
        return player_money
    elif buy == 'yes':
        print('_____________')
        lottery_results = ['x', 'o', 'p', 'k', 'm', 'e', 'a', 'w']
        a = random.choice(lottery_results)
        b = random.choice(lottery_results)
        c = random.choice(lottery_results)
        d = random.choice(lottery_results)
        e = random.choice(lottery_results)
        f = random.choice(lottery_results)
        print('| ' + a + ' | ' + b + ' | ' + c + ' |')
        print('|_' + d + '_|_' + e + '_|_' + f + '_|')
        if...
```

I Have no idea what to put after

```
if...
```

I don't want to make if for all possible solutions since that would be like 2 million ifs.

I want to make it like below

```
If 2 of the str in a or b or c or d or e or f is the same:
    print('Since 2 matched, you won $300!')
    player_money += 300
    return player_money
```

I don't know how to code(ify) the phrase that goes after if and the phrase that goes after if that I put in wouldn't work and there would be a error

Any suggestions on how I could make this work?

Comment: By "But that definitely wouldn't work", I meant that I don't know how to code(ify) the phrase that goes after if and the phrase that goes after if that I put in wouldn't work and there would be a error

Comment: Another typo, "If 2 of the str in lottery_result is the same", I meant "If 2 of the str in a or b or c or d or e or f is the same"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're off to a good start, but there is something that could make your life a lot easier. Firstly, lets use `random.choices` to create a list from the possible letters:

```
import random

pool = ['x', 'o', 'p', 'k', 'm', 'e', 'a', 'w']
results = random.choices(pool, k=len(pool))
```

*Note: k can be any integer - it determines the length of the resulting list*

This is going to yield a list with random letters from the `pool`:

```
['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'x', 'k', 'o', 'p']
```

Now, you can think about how you can build your `if` statement off of a list.

> If 2 of the str in a or b or c or d or e or f is the same:

This sounds like a job for iteration. Remember, we don't have the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. anymore; rather, they're stored in a list.

```
for letter in pool:
    if results.count(letter) > 1:
        # match found
```

Above, you iterate through the `pool` variable, which holds all of the possible values. On every loop of that iteration, we check if the current `letter` that resides inside the `pool` list exists more than once in the `results` list. This means that there was a match.

### More

You can dynamically increase the player's money count with only a few lines if you keep a list of the possible winnings that correspond with a certain number of matches. For example,

```
winnings = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800]
```

Here, `100` is chosen if there are two of the same letter (1 match). If there are three of the same letter (2 matches), `200` is chosen.

```
player_money = 0
for letter in pool:
    result_count = results.count(letter)
    player_money += winnings[result_count-2] if result_count > 1 else 0
```

Above, the line `winnings[result_count-2] if result_count > 1 else 0` determines how much the player should receive based off of their matches. We have to subtract 2 from `result_count` because, remember, python indexing starts from `0`, and if there are two of the same letter in the resulting list (1 match), we need to subtract 2 to make it 0, which selects the correct winnings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.sample()` to gather 6 results in a single line.

Then we can simply loop over the sample and check if each draw exists in `lottery_results`. It also may be better to store the winnings in a `dict` so we can easily retrieve the amount without too much hassle.

```
import random

winnings = {6: 100000, 5: 50000, 4: 10000, 3: 1000, 2: 300}

lottery_results = ['x', 'o', 'p', 'k', 'm', 'e', 'a', 'w']

user_numbers = random.sample(lottery_results, 6)
#['m', 'k', 'e', 'a', 'x', 'p']

matches = 0

for draw in user_numbers:
    if draw in lottery_results:
        matches += 1

print(f'Congrats! You matched {matches} and won ${winnings[matches]}')

#Congrats! You matched 6 and won $100000
```

---

You have further issues with the way you have set out to achieve your goal. You're generating the results for the `draw` from the results of the `house`. This means you will always match 6.

We can show this by implementing a `possible_draws` to generate both our results and user draws from. We will use the alphabet as an example.

```
import string

possible_draws = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

lottery_results = random.sample(possible_draws, 8)
#['x', 'h', 'o', 'p', 'j', 'n', 'm', 'c']

user_draws = random.sample(possible_draws, 6)
#['h', 'r', 'u', 't', 'f', 'n']

matches = 0
for draw in user_draws:
    if draw in lottery_results:
        matches += 1

if matches < 2:
    print('No win this time!')
else:
    print(f'Congrats! You matched {matches} and won ${winnings[matches]}')
```

Comment: Always matched 6

Comment: @SimonChoi Of course in its current state it will always match 6. Your code generates 6 elements from a list. Then it checks if all 6 exist in that list. You should generate your lottery_results and possible draws separately.

Comment: @SimonChoi  I have added a section to the answer to address the other issue.

Comment: I want it to check if there are any overlapping letters in Userdraws. For example, If the code randomly generated 6 letters and 3 of them are same. It would print ('3 matched, you win $money')

Comment: @SimonChoi Unless im mis understanding, this is exactly what this does?.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go by your own code then, You can use Counter.

```
from itertools import Counter
```

then you can use it like:

```
Counter([a,b,c,d,e,f]))
```

to check if any of the values is 2.